# Counting elements in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, count, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to count the nested elements in a multidimensional array. At first I thought I could use COUNT_RECURSIVE, but that counts everything. So I've tried two different approaches, none of them appeal to me. Is there a better way to do it?

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($topics as $t) {
    foreach ($t as $c) {
    $count++; 
    }
}
echo $count;

// or

echo (count($topics, COUNT_RECURSIVE)-count($topics));
```

Comment: Your first code block does what any PHP function would have to do to get the answer you want.

Comment: You answered your own question, the second method is correct and the only method I would recommend.

Comment: I'm thinking you want to count the array elements with values, but not those with arrays in them?  Also, you mention *multidimensional* arrays - are we talking arbitrary dimensions, or just 2?

Comment: His second code block is much faster and will always yield the same result.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the first block is the fastest. What makes you say otherwise @Mike?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RcV4EADd Here is a print_r of the $topics array. Both blocks return '20' as expected, and as they should btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function countNested($arr) {
    return (count($arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this code:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($topics as $t) {
    $count+= count($t); 
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: I think it count elements in two-dimensional array. I don't like the COUNT_RECURSIVE form, it is too counter intuitive for me.

Answer (score 0):

//The following example will count either one-dimensional or two-dimensional arrays

```
$values_count = (count($values, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($values)?:count($values));
```